# ISO 4217 - How Do I retrieve the numeric value(840) for the currency code "USD" in .NET?

Tags: .net, internationalization

For the currency code ISO 4217, how do I retrieve the numeric value from within the .NET framework?

For example, the numeric value for the US Dollar is 840.

[ISO Code 4217](https://www.iso.org/iso-4217-currency-codes.html)

Comment: Numeric value of what? Retrieve from where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISO3166 currency codes (840 for U.S. Dollar, etc.) are not available in the .Net framework. All you can get from the `RegionInfo` class is the ISO4217 currency code (`ISOCurrencyCode`) (e.g. USD) and the CurrencySymbol (e.g. $).

You will, I'm afraid, have to download a list of the data and do the mapping yourself.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but I just ran into this myself and thought a code solution to the problem might be helpful.

---

**VB.Net**

```
Namespace Utils.CurrencyUtils

    Public Class Iso4217Lookup

        ' Michael Krzenski
        ' 2/20/2013
        ' ISO4217 Information gathered from:
        ' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
        ' http://www.commondatahub.com/static/geography/currency/country_currency_codes.0000000001.html

        Private Shared _notFoundDefinition As New Iso4217Definition("NotFound", -1, -1)
        Private Shared _definitionCollection As New List(Of Iso4217Definition) From {
                New Iso4217Definition("AED", 784, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AFN", 971, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ALL", 8, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AMD", 51, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ANG", 532, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AOA", 973, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ARS", 32, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AUD", 36, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AWG", 533, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("AZN", 944, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BAM", 977, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BBD", 52, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BDT", 50, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BGN", 975, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BHD", 48, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("BIF", 108, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("BMD", 60, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BND", 96, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BOB", 68, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BOV", 984, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BRL", 986, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BSD", 44, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BTN", 64, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BWP", 72, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("BYR", 974, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("BZD", 84, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CAD", 124, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CDF", 976, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CHE", 947, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CHF", 756, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CHW", 948, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CLF", 990, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("CLP", 152, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("CNY", 156, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("COP", 170, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("COU", 970, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CRC", 188, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CUC", 931, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CUP", 192, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("CVE", 132, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("CZK", 203, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("DJF", 262, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("DKK", 208, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("DOP", 214, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("DZD", 12, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("EGP", 818, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ERN", 232, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ETB", 230, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("EUR", 978, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("FJD", 242, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("FKP", 238, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GBP", 826, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GEL", 981, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GHS", 936, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GIP", 292, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GMD", 270, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GNF", 324, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("GTQ", 320, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("GYD", 328, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("HKD", 344, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("HNL", 340, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("HRK", 191, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("HTG", 332, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("HUF", 348, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("IDR", 360, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ILS", 376, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("INR", 356, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("IQD", 368, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("IRR", 364, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("ISK", 352, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("JMD", 388, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("JOD", 400, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("JPY", 392, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("KES", 404, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("KGS", 417, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("KHR", 116, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("KMF", 174, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("KPW", 408, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("KRW", 410, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("KWD", 414, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("KYD", 136, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("KZT", 398, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LAK", 418, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("LBP", 422, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("LKR", 144, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LRD", 430, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LSL", 426, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LTL", 440, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LVL", 428, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("LYD", 434, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("MAD", 504, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MDL", 498, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MGA", 969, 0.7),
                New Iso4217Definition("MKD", 807, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("MMK", 104, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("MNT", 496, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MOP", 446, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MRO", 478, 0.7),
                New Iso4217Definition("MUR", 480, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MVR", 462, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MWK", 454, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MXN", 484, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MXV", 979, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MYR", 458, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("MZN", 943, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NAD", 516, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NGN", 566, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NIO", 558, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NOK", 578, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NPR", 524, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("NZD", 554, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("OMR", 512, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("PAB", 590, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PEN", 604, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PGK", 598, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PHP", 608, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PKR", 586, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PLN", 985, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("PYG", 600, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("QAR", 634, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("RON", 946, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("RSD", 941, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("RUB", 643, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("RWF", 646, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("SAR", 682, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SBD", 90, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SCR", 690, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SDG", 938, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SEK", 752, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SGD", 702, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SHP", 654, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SLL", 694, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("SOS", 706, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SRD", 968, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SSP", 728, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("STD", 678, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("SYP", 760, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("SZL", 748, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("THB", 764, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TJS", 972, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TMT", 934, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TND", 788, 3),
                New Iso4217Definition("TOP", 776, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TRY", 949, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TTD", 780, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TWD", 901, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("TZS", 834, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("UAH", 980, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("UGX", 800, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("USD", 840, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("USN", 997, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("USS", 998, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("UYI", 940, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("UYU", 858, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("UZS", 860, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("VEF", 937, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("VND", 704, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("VUV", 548, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("WST", 882, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("XAF", 950, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("XCD", 951, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("XOF", 952, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("XPF", 953, 0),
                New Iso4217Definition("YER", 886, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ZAR", 710, 2),
                New Iso4217Definition("ZMW", 967, 2)
            }

        Public Shared Function LookupByCode(ByVal code As String) As Iso4217Definition
            Dim def = _definitionCollection.Where(Function(d) d.Code = code.ToUpper()).SingleOrDefault
            If def Is Nothing Then def = _notFoundDefinition
            Return def
        End Function

        Public Shared Function LookupByNumber(ByVal number As Integer) As Iso4217Definition
            Dim def = _definitionCollection.Where(Function(d) d.Number = number).SingleOrDefault
            If def Is Nothing Then def = _notFoundDefinition
            Return def
        End Function

        Public Class Iso4217Definition
            Private _code As String
            Private _number As Integer
            Private _exponent As Integer
            Public ReadOnly Property Code As String
                Get
                    Return _code
                End Get
            End Property
            Public ReadOnly Property Number As Integer
                Get
                    Return _number
                End Get
            End Property
            Public ReadOnly Property Exponent As Integer
                Get
                    Return _exponent
                End Get
            End Property
            Public Sub New(ByVal code As String,
                           ByVal number As Integer,
                           ByVal exponent As Integer)
                _code = code
                _number = number
                _exponent = exponent
            End Sub
        End Class

    End Class

End Namespace
```

---

**C#**

```
namespace Utils.CurrencyUtils
{

    public class Iso4217Lookup
    {

        // Michael Krzenski
        // 2/20/2013
        // ISO4217 Information gathered from:
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
        // http://www.commondatahub.com/static/geography/currency/country_currency_codes.0000000001.html

        private static Iso4217Definition _notFoundDefinition = new Iso4217Definition("NotFound", -1, -1);
        private static List<Iso4217Definition> _definitionCollection = new List<Iso4217Definition> {
            new Iso4217Definition("AED", 784, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AFN", 971, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ALL", 8, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AMD", 51, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ANG", 532, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AOA", 973, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ARS", 32, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AUD", 36, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AWG", 533, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AZN", 944, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BAM", 977, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BBD", 52, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BDT", 50, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BGN", 975, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BHD", 48, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("BIF", 108, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("BMD", 60, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BND", 96, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BOB", 68, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BOV", 984, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BRL", 986, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BSD", 44, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BTN", 64, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BWP", 72, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BYR", 974, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("BZD", 84, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CAD", 124, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CDF", 976, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHE", 947, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHF", 756, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHW", 948, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CLF", 990, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CLP", 152, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CNY", 156, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("COP", 170, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("COU", 970, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CRC", 188, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CUC", 931, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CUP", 192, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CVE", 132, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CZK", 203, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DJF", 262, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("DKK", 208, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DOP", 214, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DZD", 12, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("EGP", 818, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ERN", 232, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ETB", 230, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("EUR", 978, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("FJD", 242, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("FKP", 238, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GBP", 826, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GEL", 981, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GHS", 936, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GIP", 292, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GMD", 270, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GNF", 324, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("GTQ", 320, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GYD", 328, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HKD", 344, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HNL", 340, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HRK", 191, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HTG", 332, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HUF", 348, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("IDR", 360, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ILS", 376, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("INR", 356, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("IQD", 368, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("IRR", 364, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("ISK", 352, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("JMD", 388, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("JOD", 400, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("JPY", 392, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KES", 404, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KGS", 417, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KHR", 116, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KMF", 174, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KPW", 408, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KRW", 410, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KWD", 414, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("KYD", 136, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KZT", 398, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LAK", 418, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("LBP", 422, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("LKR", 144, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LRD", 430, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LSL", 426, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LTL", 440, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LVL", 428, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LYD", 434, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("MAD", 504, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MDL", 498, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MGA", 969, 0.7),
            new Iso4217Definition("MKD", 807, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("MMK", 104, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("MNT", 496, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MOP", 446, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MRO", 478, 0.7),
            new Iso4217Definition("MUR", 480, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MVR", 462, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MWK", 454, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MXN", 484, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MXV", 979, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MYR", 458, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MZN", 943, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NAD", 516, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NGN", 566, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NIO", 558, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NOK", 578, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NPR", 524, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NZD", 554, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("OMR", 512, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("PAB", 590, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PEN", 604, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PGK", 598, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PHP", 608, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PKR", 586, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PLN", 985, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PYG", 600, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("QAR", 634, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RON", 946, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RSD", 941, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RUB", 643, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RWF", 646, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SAR", 682, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SBD", 90, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SCR", 690, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SDG", 938, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SEK", 752, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SGD", 702, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SHP", 654, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SLL", 694, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SOS", 706, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SRD", 968, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SSP", 728, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("STD", 678, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SYP", 760, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SZL", 748, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("THB", 764, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TJS", 972, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TMT", 934, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TND", 788, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("TOP", 776, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TRY", 949, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TTD", 780, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TWD", 901, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TZS", 834, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UAH", 980, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UGX", 800, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USD", 840, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USN", 997, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USS", 998, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UYI", 940, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("UYU", 858, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UZS", 860, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("VEF", 937, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("VND", 704, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("VUV", 548, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("WST", 882, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("XAF", 950, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("XCD", 951, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("XOF", 952, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("XPF", 953, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("YER", 886, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ZAR", 710, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ZMW", 967, 2)

        };
        public static Iso4217Definition LookupByCode(string code)
        {
            dynamic def = _definitionCollection.Where(d => d.Code == code.ToUpper()).SingleOrDefault;
            if (def == null)
                def = _notFoundDefinition;
            return def;
        }

        public static Iso4217Definition LookupByNumber(int number)
        {
            dynamic def = _definitionCollection.Where(d => d.Number == number).SingleOrDefault;
            if (def == null)
                def = _notFoundDefinition;
            return def;
        }

        public class Iso4217Definition
        {
            private string _code;
            private int _number;
            private int _exponent;
            public string Code {
                get { return _code; }
            }
            public int Number {
                get { return _number; }
            }
            public int Exponent {
                get { return _exponent; }
            }
            public Iso4217Definition(string code, int number, int exponent)
            {
                _code = code;
                _number = number;
                _exponent = exponent;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The constructor of Iso4217Definition expects exponent to be an int but when you create new Iso4217Definition("MGA", 969, 0.7) it is a decimal.

Comment: The values 0.7 for MRO and MGA seem wrong. Why 0.7? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217 has `2` instead

Answer (score 5):

Here is a cleaned up C# version

```
    public class Iso4217Lookup
{
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217
    private static readonly List<Iso4217Definition> DefinitionCollection = new List<Iso4217Definition> {
        new Iso4217Definition("AED", 784, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AFN", 971, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ALL", 8, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AMD", 51, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ANG", 532, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AOA", 973, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ARS", 32, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AUD", 36, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AWG", 533, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("AZN", 944, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BAM", 977, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BBD", 52, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BDT", 50, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BGN", 975, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BHD", 48, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("BIF", 108, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("BMD", 60, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BND", 96, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BOB", 68, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BOV", 984, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BRL", 986, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BSD", 44, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BTN", 64, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BWP", 72, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("BYR", 974, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("BZD", 84, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CAD", 124, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CDF", 976, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CHE", 947, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CHF", 756, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CHW", 948, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CLF", 990, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("CLP", 152, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("CNY", 156, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("COP", 170, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("COU", 970, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CRC", 188, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CUC", 931, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CUP", 192, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("CVE", 132, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("CZK", 203, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("DJF", 262, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("DKK", 208, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("DOP", 214, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("DZD", 12, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("EGP", 818, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ERN", 232, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ETB", 230, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("EUR", 978, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("FJD", 242, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("FKP", 238, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GBP", 826, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GEL", 981, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GHS", 936, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GIP", 292, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GMD", 270, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GNF", 324, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("GTQ", 320, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("GYD", 328, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("HKD", 344, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("HNL", 340, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("HRK", 191, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("HTG", 332, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("HUF", 348, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("IDR", 360, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ILS", 376, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("INR", 356, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("IQD", 368, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("IRR", 364, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("ISK", 352, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("JMD", 388, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("JOD", 400, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("JPY", 392, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("KES", 404, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("KGS", 417, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("KHR", 116, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("KMF", 174, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("KPW", 408, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("KRW", 410, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("KWD", 414, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("KYD", 136, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("KZT", 398, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LAK", 418, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("LBP", 422, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("LKR", 144, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LRD", 430, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LSL", 426, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LTL", 440, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LVL", 428, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("LYD", 434, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("MAD", 504, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MDL", 498, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MGA", 969, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MKD", 807, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("MMK", 104, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("MNT", 496, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MOP", 446, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MRO", 478, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MUR", 480, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MVR", 462, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MWK", 454, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MXN", 484, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MXV", 979, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MYR", 458, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("MZN", 943, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NAD", 516, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NGN", 566, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NIO", 558, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NOK", 578, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NPR", 524, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("NZD", 554, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("OMR", 512, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("PAB", 590, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PEN", 604, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PGK", 598, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PHP", 608, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PKR", 586, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PLN", 985, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("PYG", 600, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("QAR", 634, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("RON", 946, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("RSD", 941, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("RUB", 643, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("RWF", 646, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("SAR", 682, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SBD", 90, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SCR", 690, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SDG", 938, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SEK", 752, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SGD", 702, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SHP", 654, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SLL", 694, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("SOS", 706, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SRD", 968, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SSP", 728, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("STD", 678, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("SYP", 760, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("SZL", 748, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("THB", 764, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TJS", 972, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TMT", 934, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TND", 788, 3),
        new Iso4217Definition("TOP", 776, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TRY", 949, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TTD", 780, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TWD", 901, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("TZS", 834, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("UAH", 980, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("UGX", 800, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("USD", 840, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("USN", 997, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("USS", 998, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("UYI", 940, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("UYU", 858, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("UZS", 860, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("VEF", 937, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("VND", 704, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("VUV", 548, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("WST", 882, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("XAF", 950, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("XCD", 951, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("XOF", 952, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("XPF", 953, 0),
        new Iso4217Definition("YER", 886, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ZAR", 710, 2),
        new Iso4217Definition("ZMW", 967, 2)

    };

    public static Iso4217Definition LookupByCode(string code)
    {
        return DefinitionCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Code == code.ToUpper()) ?? Iso4217Definition.NotFound();
    }

    public static Iso4217Definition LookupByNumber(int number)
    {
        return DefinitionCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Number == number) ?? Iso4217Definition.NotFound();
    }

    public class Iso4217Definition
    {
        private readonly string _code;
        private readonly int _number;
        private readonly int _exponent;
        public bool Found { get; set; }

        public string Code
        {
            get { return _code; }
        }

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _number; }
        }

        public int Exponent
        {
            get { return _exponent; }
        }

        private Iso4217Definition() {}

        public Iso4217Definition(string code, int number, int exponent)
        {
            _code = code;
            _number = number;
            _exponent = exponent;
            Found = true;
        }

        public static Iso4217Definition NotFound()
        {
            return new Iso4217Definition { Found = false };
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: FYI, for MRO and MGA you put 2 in, but Wikipedia says 1 (with comment)

Comment: I know it's obvious, but don't forget `using System.Collections.Generic;` and `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of the file