# Get alphabetical currency iso code from numerical iso currency code in C#

Tags: c#, .net, currency

I need a method, which takes ISO-4217 numeric currency code as a parameter and returns respective alphabetical currency code. Is there a solution for this in .NET libraries or do I have to write my custom method?

Comment: The framework only has the alphabetic codes, in the form of `RegionInfo.ISOCurrencySymbol`. Even that is tied to regions that the framework knows about. You want your own mapping/database.

Comment: [Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156159/iso-4217-how-do-i-retrieve-the-numeric-value840-for-the-currency-code-usd) that asks the opposite (numeric codes from characters), but there are some answers that allow lookups either way.  They're a few years old, so you might want to check the mappings are current.